# Выводить из mysql по городам

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы user и info
В таблице user храниться id пользователя и его город, а в таблице info есть так же id пользователя, город и еще два поля, подскажите как вывести пользователю всю инфу с таблицы info, для его города?

Comment: составь запрос через `JOIN`

Comment: В `info` у каждого пользователя только тот же самый город или там у пользователей бывает по нескольку городов и надо выбрать информацию только по родному городу? Можете добавить названия полей в таблицах?

Comment: *всю инфу с таблицы info, для его города* - про всех пользователей из города заданного пользователя?

Comment: У пользователя только один город. Основная проблема, мне надо вывести разную инфу для пользователей, скажем если пользователь с города Икс то со второй таблицы выводим всю инфу с города икс. Со всех строк где есть такой же город. сами таблицы название таблицы user поля user_id, city название таблицы help поля user_id, title, city, message

Comment: всю инфу с таблицы info, для его города

Comment: Александр, зачем во второй таблице присутствует город, если его можно однозначно определить по первой таблице с помощью user_id ?

Comment: Что бы можно было определить к какому городу относится сообщение

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что город во второй таблице может быть любым, не обязательно городом пользователя?

Comment: До меня дошло )) город таки не нужен ), я согласен что поле город можно удалить, но как можно тогда вывести инфу для пользователей по городам?

Comment: Вернее если я с города икс, как вывести что бы была вся информация для города икс

Comment: Проверьте формулировку задачи: Есть таблица пользователей (код пользователя,  город) и таблица сообщений (код пользователя, заголовок, сообщение). На входе город. На выходе - список сообщений от пользователей из этого же города. Что поправите?

Comment: Все верно, вы очень правильно написали задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Задача**:
Есть таблица пользователей `user` (код пользователя `user_id`, город `city`) и таблица сообщений `help` (код пользователя `user_id`, заголовок `title`, сообщение `message`). На входе город `$city`. На выходе - список сообщений от пользователей из этого же города.

```
SELECT title, message FROM help h, user u WHERE h.user_id = u.user_id and city = '$city'
```

**Итоговый код, сообща отлаженный в комментариях**

```
<?php $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","login","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$db); mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT h.title, h.message FROM cms_sos h,
cms_user_profiles u WHERE h.user_id = u.user_id AND u.city = '" .
$inUser->city . "' LIMIT 10",$db);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) echo '<p><b>' .
$myrow['title']. '</b><br>' . $myrow['message']. '</p>';
mysql_close($db); ?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39101/discussion-on-answer-by-gleb-kemarsky---mysql--).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрПшеничный Добавил итоговый код в ответ. Если всё ок, нажмите на галочку сбоку от ответа, что он принят. [Tour]